# Hosting Sql Server reporting service to iis

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, reporting-services

I have created one solution in Business intelligence studio (SQl Server Reporting). Now i want to deploy it on IIS server . Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Do you have the server-side SQL Server Reporting Services components installed somewhere?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server Reporting Services do you plan to install? Newer versions no longer require IIS, as they hook to http.sys directly.

Comment: Please avoid using the tags mistakenly. For example, sql tag is used for questions on the SQL language, while reporting tag is more general about the reporting mechanism. When you just query about SSRS, you should use reporting-services tag.

Comment: sql server reporting version is : 10.50.1600.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS, in recent versions, including the one that you mention, no longer use IIS as a service component. They instead connect directly to the Windows http.sys, as mentioned in comments.

If you have built reports in Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), then you will need to deploy to a server install of SSRS. This is installed as an optional component of a SQL Server. You can install SSRS (the server) on a machine that does not have other components of SQL Server installed, but this is usually restricted by license agreements. As mentioned, SSRS will not require IIS to be installed; you can specify the bindings and configuration through the SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration Tool installed with SSRS.

Comment: Thanks for such useful information. I am using hosting panel of third party. so if i want to use SSRS i should have SSRS server to be installed on my hosting panel .. right ????

Comment: If you want to deploy the reports directly, then yes. There are ways to build views of the reports into an application as well: search on ReportViewer and .rdlc for examples.